# What is the meaning of zmq.Poller.poll( 1000 )?

Tags: python, zeromq, poller

I searched already but I still don't understand what's this line meaning.

Why put 1000 in the function?

[full code is here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:asyncsrv)

```
class ClientTask(threading.Thread):
    """ClientTask"""
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

    def run(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        identity = u'worker-%d' % self.id
        socket.identity = identity.encode('ascii')
        socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5570')
        print('Client %s started' % (identity))
        poll = zmq.Poller()
        poll.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
        reqs = 0
        while True:
            reqs = reqs + 1
            print('Req #%d sent..' % (reqs))
            socket.send_string(u'request #%d' % (reqs))
            for i in range(5):
                sockets = dict(poll.poll(1000))//HERE
                if socket in sockets:
                    msg = socket.recv()
                    tprint('Client %s received: %s' % (identity, msg))

        socket.close()
        context.term()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `1000` is the timeout in milliseconds to wait for an event.

[See more here](http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.poll).

Comment: Could you explain me what's dict(poll.poll(1000)) meaning?

Comment: Well, the fully elaborated answer is above, the `Poller` instance ( called a bit mystically confusing a **`poll`** ( the same name as it's method `.poll()` ) returned values are re-wraped into a python dictionary, using the out-most function **`dict()`**. The internal behaviour of **`poll.poll( aTimeoutInMILLISECONDs )`** uses a time-out mechanics, so as to avoid remaining infinitely hung-up in case, such `poll.register(...)`-ed sockets do not deliver any event a `Poller`-instance is waiting for. Blocking is not welcome here, so the timeout was set ~1000[ms] so the code will for sure continue

Answer (score 3):

### Why?

Because if there were not put any value ( or if a value of `0` would be explicitly used there ), the `Poller.poll()` method would have to wait infinitely for any first event on a configured set of such `Poller`-instance monitored `Socket`-instances.

### What would that mean?

In such a case, the call of a `Poller.poll()`-method **will block**, until any such event appears ( if it appears ), with a non-zero probability, that no such event ever arrives at all.

That case would effectively **hang-up** your application in an endless ( and totally un-controllable from inside of your code ) wait-state, **which is exactly the reason to prevent** and avoid entering into such state a **`Poller.poll( aTimeoutInMILLISECONDs )` prevents this by the very method of setting the timeout.**

Comment: thanks for your help.<br/>It’s clear to me now.<br/>

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [zmq.Poller](http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html#zmq.Poller), the argument for the `poll()` method is the timeout in milliseconds. It returns tuples of the form `(socket, event)` when registered events on the registered sockets. In this case we are only looking for inbound messages on one socket: `poll.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)`.

More details can be found in the matching section of [The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Asynchronous-Client-Server-Pattern).